# HTTP 500 Internal Server Error when executing client javascript in any XPage

Tags: javascript, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I created in my Lotus Domino server a new application which is totally empty. I then created an `XPage`, and in it I modified the `onClientLoad event`, adding this client javascript code: `alert("Hola");`. When I preview the `XPage` on the browser, I get an HTTP 500 internal server error. The error on the server's log is this one:

```
26/06/2013 12:54:27   HTTP JVM: SEVERE: CLFAD####E: Exception thrown
26/06/2013 12:54:27   HTTP JVM: SEVERE: CLFAD####E: Exception occurred servicing request for: /Pruebajs.nsf/prueba.xsp - HTTP Code: 500
26/06/2013 12:54:27   HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception [/Pruebajs.nsf/prueba.xsp]
```

If I preview the same `XPage` on the Notes Client, the javascript code is run successfully.

I then created a similar application in my local machine instead of in the server, and the javascript code is run successfully, both in the web browser and the Notes client.

So it looks like some kind of configuration issue in our Domino server (maybe authorizations?), but we do not know where to look.

Comment: Not sure, but could be a signage issue. Does the person who signed the XPage have server permissions to run code?

Comment: In Domino Designer go to `Application Properties > XPages (tab)` check  `Display XPage runtime error page`. This would give you more details.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/10190080/error-500-in-each-xpage go through answers to this question to address your problem.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I checked the option Naveen suggested (Display XPage runtime error), and it turns out that the problem is that my Lotus Designer version is 8.5.3 and the Domino server version is 8.5 (I did not know about that). This note explains it all: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPagesPageVersions.htm. The problem had to do with the change in xp:eventHandler from version 8.5 to version 8.5.1. The workaround of changing the syntax by hand in the page source works, but we had better upgrade our server or downgrade the Designer.

Comment: @CarlosMunoz-Juste Combine the information from Naveen's comment with your details from your comment and post as an answer.

Comment: 8.5.0 for XPages is plain painful when you look what 8.5.3 or 9.0 can do. Can we help to convince somebody to get your server current?

Comment: I'll try to convince the Domino admin and the IT manager. I am posting the answer now. Yesterday I could not because my stackoverflow reputation is too low and I cannot answer my own question until 8 hours have passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody for your help. Naveen's advice proved very useful. After checking "Display XPage runtime error" on Designer (Application -> Properties -> Tab XPages), the error message was much more meaningful:

```
            The generated page version 8.5 is not compatible with the server version 3.0, for the page /prueba.xsp.
```

The problem is that my Notes Client and Designer are a higher (8.5.3) version than the Domino Server (8.5). According to this note: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPagesPageVersions.htm, the eventHandler syntax has been changed slightly, and this causes the XPage to be marked as version 8.5.1. This also explains why it works when the database is local!

I have tried the workaround suggested in the note (altering  in the page source back the event handler syntax to the 8.5 form), and it works. Now I will try to convince people around here to upgrade the server.

Thanks,

Carlos

Comment: If you need help from IBM for the convincing, let me know